работа с текстом и ячейками в Excel
Всем добра!
Собственно вопрос:
Может ли Excel (совместно с VBA) сделать так чтобы когда я ввожу в ячейку A1 какой-то текст и при достижении длины строки (текста) в 30 символов курсор сам переместился на ячейку A2 и я продолжаю вводить текст. При этом была проверка на целостность слов?

Может ли Excel (совместно с VBA) .. Нет. Вы можете написать метод, который ПОСЛЕ ввода значения по нажатию Enter раскидает введённое значение по ячейкам.

В чём смысл, задача какая?

Задача в том, чтобы не шибко умный пользователь не лазил, не тыкал кнопки, а просто открыл подготовленный файл документа Excel, на котором уже есть определённая таблица, и в одном из столбцов начал вводить текст, не задумываясь, что необходимо соблюсти длину строки и переключиться на новую строку ниже, клацая всё время Enter, когда ширина столбца уже превышена, а просто печатал то, что ему нужно.

Я так и думал. Тогда это просто второй вариант.


Option Explicit

Sub LimitedInput()
  Dim s As String, t As String, sa, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  Do
    s = InputBox("Введите текст")
    If s = "" Then Exit Do
    sa = Split(s): t = ""
    For j = LBound(sa) To UBound(sa)
      If Len(t) + Len(sa(j)) < 30 Then
        t = t & " " & sa(j)
      Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = Mid(t, 2)
        i = i + 1: t = " " & sa(j)
      End If
    Next
    If Len(t) > 0 Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = Mid(t, 2)
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Loop
End Sub



Спасибо! Плюсанул.
